# Math.ceil and Math.rint methods returning same value

Tags: java

The `Math.rint()` and `Math.ceil()` methods return the same value, can anyone please explain why?
What is the difference between these methods? When to use `Math.rint()` and where to use `Math.ceil()` ?

```
public class BasicMathDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double b = 43.74;
        System.out.println("The rint of "+ b +" is : "+Math.rint(b));
        System.out.println("The ceiling of " + b +" is: "+ Math.ceil(b));

    }
}
```

Output is:

```
The rint of 43.74 is : 44.0
The ceiling of 43.74 is: 44.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.rint()` rounds your number to the closest Integer. [See](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_rint.htm)

`Math.ceil()` rounds-up your number to the closest highier Integer. [See](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_ceil.htm)

`Math.floor()` rounds-down your number to the closest lower Integer. [See](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_floor.htm)

Example:

```
float number = 3.38;
double rint = Math.rint(number); // This will return 3
double ceil = Math.ceil(number); // This will return 4
double floor = Math.floor(number); // This will return 3
```

Comment: Your wording isn't consistent with your example. rint rounds down in your case but up in OP's.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Yeah I'm using 3.38 So it will round up to 3 (to down) because 3.38 < 3.5 OP uses 43.74 which is greater than 4.5 hence it will rounded up to 75.

Comment: I realize this might be a language issue but this is erroneous. Rounding in general means to go to the *closest* number; rounding *up* means to go to a *larger* number, and rounding *down* means to go to a *smaller* number. It's incorrect to say each of your examples "rounds-up."

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Ah I see. Sorry. I'm not that good at English. Thanks for pointing it. I edited it.

Answer (score 2):

They return the same value because that's how they were designed to work for the given example.

`rint`:

> "Returns the double value that is closest in value to the argument and
>   is equal to a mathematical integer."

and `ceil`:

> "Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double value that
>   is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a
>   mathematical integer."

as seen [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html).

So, in both cases, they round up. If you want to see an example of them returning different values use 43.4 - for example.

You would use them where they will give you the desired results. Ceiling will only give you a number greater than or equal to the passed value. On the other hand, it's possible to get a number less than the passed with `rint`.

Answer (score 0):

Assume an array [1.1,2.9]
ceil gives 2,3
flo0r gives 1,2
rint gives  1,3